# Desplegar un repositorio de gitlab con CD/CI y lftp

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Estoy intentando desplegar desde un pipeline de gitlab en un servidor que tiene cpanels, no tiene ssh y únicamente vía ssh, estoy siguiendo el artículo https://savjee.be/2019/04/gitlab-ci-deploy-to-ftp-with-lftp/ para usar lftp, pero después de ejecutar composer se me queda así:

```
Usage: user <user|URL> [<pass>]
```

Entiendo por lo que devuelve que no llega a conectar al servidor y se queda en la validación del usuario.